# Select in sql from 2 tables using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with my select, so I have 2 tables in my DB:

```
USER
id       name        is_admin        is_verificator
DOCUMENT
id       date        admin           verificator
```

Where document.admin is foreign key which links user table

And if I have insert the lines:

```
1      John           Y            N
2      Patrick        N            Y
```

and:

```
1       24/08/2014    1            2
```

After the select I want to obtain for this document who is the verificator and the admin

```
John   Patrick

public function getOneDosar()
{
    $uid = (int) $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
    $this->load->database();
    $get_dosar = $this->db->query("select
                                    d.date,
                                    u1.name,
                                    u1.name,
                                    from document d
                                    join `users` u1 on(d.fk_user = u1.id and u1.is_admin = 'Y')
                                    join `users` u2 on(d.fk_verificator = u2.id and u2.is_verificator = 'Y')
                                    AND d.id_dosar = $uid");
    if ($get_dosar->num_rows())
    {
        $get_dosar = $get_dosar->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $get_dosar = NULL;
    }

    return $get_dosar;
}
```

Help me please

Comment: go with activerecords

Comment: Adash any ideas, please

Comment: are you want just join??

Comment: I'm noob and I cant'create this join

Comment: first make sure that primary key of first table is refer in second key as foreign key. Give the clear structure of two tables

Comment: you dont need this column at all  `verificator` in `document` table. 1 foreign key is suffcient to implement what you want!

Answer (score 0):

you can construct the query like this:

```
$this->db->select( 'd.date,u1.name, u1.name');
    $this->db->from('document d');
    $this->db->join('users u1', "d.fk_user = u1.id and u1.is_admin = 'Y'",your join like inner); 
$this->db->join('users u2 "d.fk_verificator = u2.id and u2.is_verificator = 'Y'",your join like inner);
```

Comment: I think the solution is to add 2 foreign key:
1.admin references to user.id
2.verificator references to user.id
It is a good idea?

Comment: adding foreign will give better way of kind of operation on tables and select update and other will become easy for you.